# Jenkins Pipeline Dashboard

Tags: jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

We're putting together our CI pipelines and a need we'll quickly have is the ability to visualize all pipelines, at the very least determine which ones are waiting for input.

Our general flow is very roughly:

- Deploy to dev
- Prompt QA team for QA deployment approval
- Deploy to QA
- Prompt QA team for Staging environment deployment approval
- Deploy to Staging
- QA Signoff
- Business Signoff
- Deploy to prod

With some smoke test steps in the way. Would love for the QA team to have a dashboard of which pipelines are awaiting their approval.

Even a view that shows the last invocation of every pipeline would be sufficient (you could at least quickly see which stage certain jobs are paused at - we will use the same pipeline design for most of our microservices)

Anything out there that would be useful for us?

Comment: There are several plugins that does it : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin for example. 

You can also try and write your jobs as a multi-job type which has a nice view to it (shows you all the steps that are running, etc.) 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin. 

If that is what you meant let me know and I'll write it as an answer :)

Comment: I recently saw this project: https://github.com/capitalone/Hygieia.
Looks like it does exactly what you want. However, I still not tried it for some production use-case. And for sure, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin is the best way to go. If you need some more details, let me know.

Comment: @Dan, what was your final solution?

Comment: We're using the Build Monitor plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Monitor+Plugin for now. To signify which builds are active/successful/failed.

The downside is there is no real way to distinguish between "currently building" and "waiting for input".

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely for you. I have been using this for around 6 Months now .

[Hygieia Dashboard](https://github.com/capitalone/Hygieia)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Oh, thank you for that, I am new to stack overflow. I will definitely keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AnyStatus](https://www.anystat.us/2019/09/01/jenkins-build-monitor.html) which is a desktop application for Windows that brings together metrics and events from various sources such as Jenkins, Azure DevOps, TeamCity and more. AnyStatus supports Jenkins Jobs and Views. It can also monitor other resources such as web servers, databases, operating system metrics and others.

[image]

Disclaimer: I am the author of AnyStatus.